# What is the correct definition of the particle according to experiment results?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics

I came across an [article](https://www.quantamagazine.org/what-is-a-particle-20201112) from Quanta Magazine. It discussed and explained different definitions of a particle. I would like to know which definition of the particle is the correct (or most fitting) when one is discussing experiments and experimental results.

Answer (score 1):

To use a quote from that very article you cite: "I should not say there’s a unified point of view..." ;) I doubt that people here will give a "correct" definition, as this depends on context: what experiment are you conducting?

To not leave you hanging though, I would say anything that can in the case at hand be approximated as a point where the details of its internal structure don't matter. Nuclei are a particle when you do Compton scattering, but not when you probe them at the Large Hadron Collider. And yes, entire stars can be seen as particles when all you want to do is to simulate their motion in a galaxy.

Answer (score 1):

If you read  the article carefully you would not ask. If there would be one definition agreeing with all experiments, physicist would agree on it. So none of the definitions the journal mentions really disagrees with experiments, but they explain different aspects of explaining an experiment.
So you can only hope to get different answers here from different people